Reduction with Red P/HI
I wish to know the reduction of nitrogen containing compounds with the reagent Red P/HI. So does it reduce them to alkanes or amines? The groups are as follows:

Cyanide
Isocyanide
Acid Amide
Nitro Compounds

Any kind of help along with the products of the reactions would be highly appreciated.
This question is NOT similar to previous questions asked in the website as I have listed different functional groups.

It is unclear what resources you have consulted before asking this question and what conclusion you have made from that. // Review the guide How to ask and Asking FAQs to prevent clarification requests, objections,  downvoting or closure.

https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/135349/red-phi-reduction
