# Red P+HI with some specific functional groups

Tags: organic-chemistry, organic-reduction

*I've seen the related question ([Does RedP+HI reduce all carbon functional groups to alkane?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/90696/does-redphi-reduce-all-carbon-functional-groups-to-alkane)). Although the question is admittedly similar, neither the answer provided nor the document linked in it answer my question, since they don't include the functional groups I am most interested in(since my sources have been mostly in consensus regarding the others), it's basically just alcohols, aldehydes, and ketones(with one ester, that too of the sort that gives unexpected reactions sometimes due to strange mechanisms).*

Does Red P+HI reduce esters, acid anhydrides, acid halides, cyanides, and oximes? I've checked Solomon as well as some exam-prep-type books, and just searched the web, finding a couple of pages here itself, a few sites meant for exam prep, which I know to not be 100% reliable. My teacher has basically said it reduces everything, but my generally more reliable HOD has said it would only reduce alcohols, aldehydes, ketones, and carboxylic acids to alkanes; all of this just resulting in me being more confused than before.